# Duplicate durable keys are inserted when executed 2 process parallelly in SSIS script component

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I actually have a new process to execute in SSIS. Since one of the table used in the source query have data in millions and it would take more time if we create another process using that table. So, we decided to use the package that uses the table with million records and insert data in to new table. In order to do that have used a script component, in script component took data and loaded into the new table through a stored procedure.

However, my problem is I am having a column called DKID, where the value of this is max(DKID)+1 from the table. But when executed multiple processes, duplicate DKID's are inserted.

Please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use an IDENTITY column.

Comment: No can not use identity to that column. Because, DKID is durable column, we have same DKID for a unique natural key and there are history records for those natural key.

Comment: Sorry, it is not clear to me what your comment means.